# Как вызвать функции подклассов?

Tags: c++, функции

Как из `a` вызвать `foo` и `bar`?

```
struct A {
    struct B {
        template<typename T>
        int foo() {

        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct C {
        int bar() {

        }
    };
};


int main() {
    A a;
    // ?
}
```

Comment: Но если в A нет подобъектов B и C - то *для каких объектов* вызывать `foo` и `bar`? Они же не статические.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в программе нет никаких "подклассов".

Ваша программа содержит вложенные объявления совершенно независимых классов (и шаблонов классов). Все, что дает такой стиль объявления, это изменения в именовании классов (вложенные шаблоны/классы будут именоваться `A::B` и `A::C`) и возможность доступа вложенных классов к закрытым членам охватывающего класса. Больше ничего.

В остальном эти классы остаются совершенно независимыми. У вас в программе есть объект типа `A`, но нет ни одного объекта типа `A::B` или `A::C<>`. Поэтому вызывать `foo` и `bar` нельзя - их просто не для кого вызывать. Объявите объекты и вызывайте на здоровье

```
int main()
{
  A::B b;
  b.foo<int>();

  A::C<int> c;
  c.bar();
}
```

Как видите, ни к `A`, ни к `a` это все не имеет никакого отношения. С таким же успехом вы могли объявить `B` и `C` за пределами `A`. Ничего бы не поменялось, кроме имен классов.

Answer (score 0):

Можете также  добавить функции в структуре `A`, которые просто возвращают данные функции  вложенных структур:

```
struct A {
    // ...
    template <typename T>
    int foo() {  return B().foo<T>(); }
    template <typename T >
    int bar() { return  C<T>().bar(); }
};
```

Вызывая эти функции для обьекта `A`, вы в принципе вызовите функции вложенных структур:

```
A a;
a.bar<double>();
a.foo<double>();
```